# Regex to match plurals only if an exact match is not found

Tags: regex, bash, grep

I could use a little help figuring out regex. Given a list of words in a file:

```
Peril
Is
I
Non
No
```

I'm trying to find a regex that will match a plural if necessary but only if there is not another match available. What I have at the moment:

```
#!/bin/bash
findword(){
  grep -iE "^$@?" file
}
```

If I run it like `findword perils` it returns `Peril`. That's what I want to happen.

But if I run it like `findword non` it matches both `Non` and `No`.
Same with `findword is` matches both `Is` and `I`. That's not what I want to happen. I only want non exact matches if it can't find an exact match in the list.

Comment: I may be wrong, but I think that you can't solve this only with regex. The way you need it, the regex would have to search everything to know that an exact match isn't present and only then search for a non exact match. This will require at least two loops, one searching for the exact and another one for non exact if the first can't find any.

Comment: And I thought regex could solve everything ;)

Comment: But I'd still need to figure out the correct regex for the 2nd loop.

Comment: but how would you distinguish that `peril` is fine for `perils` but `i` is not fine for `is`?

Comment: Hahah well that's why I'm here.. because I don't know. I really thought there was some magical regex way of doing this.

Comment: I might have got confused, but if you mean you want `perils` if that is found and `peril` only if `perils` was not found then you can do something like `grep -ix "$1" file || grep -ixE "$1?" file`

Comment: @Sundeep You're a genius. :) Please make this an answer.

Comment: @I0_ol Many people overestimate the power of regular expressions. They are not the end-all and be-all of matching/parsing. In fact, they are one of the *weakest* models for doing so. They are widely used because the syntax is simple and the algorithms for recognizing matches is efficient and (relatively) simple to implement.

Comment: @chepner What alternatives to regular expressions would you suggest? I know it's generally ill advised to parse html / xml with regex. But for simple text documents I always assumed regex was the way to go.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$ cat file 
Peril
Is
I
Non
No

$ findword(){ grep -ix "$1" file || grep -ix "${1::-1}" file; }
$ findword no
No
$ findword non
Non
$ findword none
Non
$ findword i
I
$ findword is
Is
```

- `-x` to force matching for entire line only
- `grep -ix "$1" file` if there is a match found, it will be printed and exit status will be `0`
- else, the command after `||` comes in to play
- `grep -ix "${1::-1}" file` check again with last character removed

  - can also use `grep -ixE "$1?" file`
- Also, can add `-F` option incase words can contain metacharacters like `.` but you want to search literally

Comment: `grep -x 'PATTERN'` is the same as `grep '^PATTERN$'`